# Overlapped Containers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: How can I achieve this using flutter]

I want to achieve that in flutter using a stream builder, where I can place a container below another and have the top one overlapping the other like in the image provided. Please, your help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guy in this UI challenge does similar thing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i38DY5Mei4w